# Custom nested form type easyadmin

Tags: forms, symfony, nested, embed, easyadmin

I have an entity *User* and an entity *Address* which are in **OneToOne** relationship. I would like to display the address type in the User Crud in EasyAdmin, and I don't find a way to do just like Symfony `->add('address', AddressType::class)`.
I tried the following options:

```
CollectionField::new('address')
            ->setEntryIsComplex(true)
            ->setEntryType(AddressType::class)
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => true
            ]),
```

But this makes the user able to add as many as addresses he wants, although I just want one.

```
AssociationField::new('address')->hideOnIndex()
```

This one makes the user choose an existing address in a list. That's not an embed of a form type.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try to use AssociationField instead of CollectionField

Comment: As I said in my post, AssociationField allows the user to choose an existing address in a list. It doesn't display the form :/

Comment: even with `->setEntryType(AddressType::class)`?

Comment: `setEntryType()` doesn't exist for AssociationField

Comment: Sorry, its `->setFormType()` here

Comment: I indeed tried `->setFormType(AddressType::class)` but got the following error 'The option "query_builder" does not exist'. I had to replace AddressType by EntityType, which removed the error, but the result was just a simple list to choose an Address (like a simple AssociationField).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is as follows:

Create Address Field like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Field;

use App\Form\AddressType;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;

final class AddressField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = 'Address'): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            // this template is used in 'index' and 'detail' pages
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/address.html.twig')
            // this is used in 'edit' and 'new' pages to edit the field contents
            // you can use your own form types too
            ->setFormType(AddressType::class)
            ->addCssClass('field-address')
        ;
    }
}
```

And then use it in your User Crud Controller

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
  // Other fields

  yield AddressField::new('address'); // Your new address field
}
```

`templates/admin/field/address.html.twig` template would be like this

```
{% if field.value is defined %}  
  <dl class="row justify-content-center">
    <dt class="col-3 text-right">City</dt>
    <dd class="col-9">{{ field.value.city }}</dd>
    <dt class="col-3 text-right">Address 1</dt>
    <dd class="col-9">{{ field.value.address1 }}</dd>
    <dt class="col-3 text-right">Address 2</dt>
    dd class="col-9">{{ field.value.address2 }}</dd>
  </dl>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think about this solution! It works like a charm!

Comment: Is there a line missing in the second comment? Whats used for edit and new?

Comment: @Max AddressType form class is used for that

Comment: @Flash I think i got it now. It was a little bit misleading for me! Thanks